# How to set environment variable R_User? And how to get module winreg?

Tags: installation, rpy2

I'm trying to run a Python program that uses rpy2. Installation was successful, I think. But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/(file location)', wdir='C:/Users/(file location)')
>
> File "C:\Users(my
>   name)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 827, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Users(my
>   name)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/(file location)", line 5, in 
>       from rpy2.robjects import r
>
> File "C:\Users(my
>   name)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects__init__.py", line 19,
>   in 
>       from rpy2.robjects.robject import RObjectMixin, RObject
>
> File "C:\Users(my
>   name)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\robject.py", line 6,
>   in 
>       rpy2.rinterface.initr()
>
> File "C:\Users(my
>   name)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface__init__.py", line
>   208, in initr
>       _initr(r_preservehash=r_preservehash)
>
> RuntimeError: R_USER not defined.

I found a question that addresses just this problem: [Rpy2 error wac-a-mole: R_USER not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414540/rpy2-error-wac-a-mole-r-user-not-defined). The answer says to set the R_user environment variable. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do that; I hadn't even heard of an environment variable before until this. I followed the only lead I saw: the link in the answer. That led to a webpage with two downloadable python files: set_Rvars32_win32.py and setup.py. I tried running both, but they both yield an error. Here is the traceback for set_Ravars32_win32.py

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/(my name)/Anaconda3/set_Rvars_win32.py', wdir='C:/Users/Jin/Anaconda3')
>
> File "C:\Users(my
>   name)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 827, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File "C:\Users(my
>   name)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/(my name)/Anaconda3/set_Rvars_win32.py", line 4, in
>   
>       import _winreg
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_winreg'

setup.py yields the same error and the same traceback sequence (except of course the file is C:/Users/(my name)/Anaconda3/setup.py)

I then tried running the Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3).

pip install _winreg yields

ERROR: Invalid requirement: '_winreg'

pip install winreg yields

Collecting winreg

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement winreg (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for winreg

Am I on the right track? Or is there an easier way to set environment variables?

Thanks

Comment: There's been a decent number of views on this question, but no responses. Even if you don't know the answer, may I at least have a response as to why no one has answered so I know how to improve the question?

Thanks

Comment: have you installed R?

Comment: Yes, I have. On my desktop, I have R i386 3.6.2 and R x64 3.6.2

Comment: in the Control Panel look for environment variables(probably Settings > Advanced System Settings >  (Advanced Tab) Environment variables). Check there, are there any R-related variables set?

Comment: There are just 4 environment variables there: OneDrive, Path, TEMP and TMP

Comment: See, there are the user and the system environment variables and you can create new. For start, try following the instructions in the top answer here (adjust r-version and your user name): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698877/how-to-setup-environment-variable-r-user-to-use-rpy2-in-python  Does that work?

Comment: Just to be sure, to **add** to Path, for example if Path was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder` change it `C:\Program Files (x86)\folder;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2\bin\x64`

Comment: @adatzer Thanks for your responses. So I didn't exactly follow that link's instructions to the letter, but I think I did something close enough. First, I went to Windows' environment variables and added R_HOME (value C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2) and R_USER (value C:\Users\(my name)\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\rpy2

Then, I created a new .py file with just the following code

Comment: from rpy2.robjects import r

print(r('''
        # create a function `f`
        f <- function(r, verbose=FALSE) {
            if (verbose) {
                cat("I am calling f().\n")
            }
            2 * pi * r
        }
        # call the function `f` with argument value 3
        f(3)
        '''))

That returned nothing. But putting a print() around it yielded [1] 18.84956.

So far so good. But when I then attempted to run my own program, I got the following error:

RRuntimeError: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Comment: i'm new SO user, but this seems like another question (got warnings for too many comments). So i'm gonna attempt a proper answer below, including some links to your RRuntimeError that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have to tweek your environment variables manually. To do this, go to the environment variables (Control Panel > System Settings > Advanced System Settings > (Advanced Tab) Environment Variables) and follow the steps from the top answer here: [How to setup environment variable R_user to use rpy2 in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698877/how-to-setup-environment-variable-r-user-to-use-rpy2-in-python) . (Make sure you *add* to the Path).

Concerning the RRuntimeError you mentioned in the comments, it's hard to tell without further info, but it seems like your code tries to open a file (or install R libraries). Check out these links:

- [Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466317/error-in-filefile-rt-cannot-open-the-connection)
- [assign variables from python to R using r.assign and then use read.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896618/assign-variables-from-python-to-r-using-r-assign-and-then-use-read-table)
- https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/399/rruntimeerror-error-in-file-file-rt-cannot